# Change data source in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tabular, sqldatasource

I want to change the source from dev server to uat server, when I try to do change source and give uat source details the database is not coming up it is still using dev database only

Suggest a way how to change the source or replace dev with uat

Answer (score 0):

1. Update Connection String:
   Open your Tabular project.
   Go to Data Source properties.
   Change the connection string to UAT details.
2. Deploy Project:
   Build and deploy the project.
3. Update Data Source:
   In Visual Studio, go to Model > Existing Connections.
   Replace the data source with UAT details.
4. Verify:
   Check data preview or run queries to ensure UAT connection.
5. Check Hardcoded References:
   Look for dev server references, update if found.

**Note**: Pay attention to error messages and ensure UAT server accessibility.